# Moving MSDB, can't access single user mode

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to move `msdb` (SQL Server 2005) by using the instructions here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071

However, when I start SQL Server in single user mode, I have no way to access the database. I have tried starting sqlcmd from the console (and also for good measure tried starting ssms), but I'm unable to get into any tool to do my work because it says it is in single user mode and only one administrator can be logged in.  In the services console I see no other SQL Server related processes running, so what is preventing me from getting in?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Some application is stealing the only connection available. See [Starting SQL Server in Single-User Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx) for a tip how to prevent that:

> When you use the `-m` option with sqlcmd or Management Studio, you can
>   limit the connections to a specified client application. For example,
>   `-m"sqlcmd"` limits connections to a single connection and that
>   connection must identify itself as the sqlcmd client program. Use this
>   option when you are starting SQL Server in single-user mode and an
>   unknown client application is taking the only available connection. To
>   connect through the Query Editor in Management Studio, use
>   `-m"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query"`.